# IPTABLES - configuring SNAT with dynamic to-source

Tags: routing, iptables, nat, docker

My development environment uses a docker swarm node with multiples microservices inside. I need make the microservices running in my machine communicate with the microservices running inside docker, however I'm having some issues to route the packages correctly. As the ip address of the containers changes when I restart the docker server, I'm trying use gateway to route the packages. Using these rules I can ping any microservice I want:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A  PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.1
```

as you can see, the microservices are running in 10.0.0.0/24 network and I'm using the gateway's ip 172.18.0.1. The problem is I can't find a way to process the response packages as I don't know wich source I should put in the rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source IP
```

Is there a way I can mark the packet and set the source ip based on the this mark? What can I do to route it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the DNAT rule to point to 172.18.0.2, as this is the ip Docker uses to map the ports of all nodes, deleted all POSTROUTING rules and only added a masquerade to all packets:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A  PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2
#delete existent POSTROUTING rule (only the rule at line one)
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
#add masquerade rule for all
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

And resulting NAT table became:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 840 packets, 89942 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      606 42480 DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2      353 27496 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
3        9   540 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/24          to:172.18.0.2

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 402 packets, 61889 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 20 packets, 1200 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       20  1200 DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2        1    60 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      710 44373 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 RETURN     all  --  ecommerce_br0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker_gwbridge *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8089 to:172.18.0.2:8089
2        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8084 to:172.18.0.2:8084
3        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083 to:172.18.0.2:8083
4        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8082 to:172.18.0.2:8082
5        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8081 to:172.18.0.2:8081
6        8   480 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 to:172.18.0.2:8080
7        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8079 to:172.18.0.2:8079
8        3   180 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2181 to:172.18.0.2:2181
9       72  4320 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9092 to:172.18.0.2:9092
10     108  6480 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8761 to:172.18.0.2:8761
11      73  4380 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432 to:172.18.0.2:5432
12     362 27840 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```